# Is there an Alt key combination to copy to clipboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been trying around some stuff while developing a software of mine, when I found out that if I use the keys' combination **Alt+022** I was able to paste what I have got on my clipboard in plenty of different text editors.

> paste† - Alt 22
>   † *Some word processing programs will not recognize these Alt functions*.
>   **Source:** [Special Characters - Alt Keys](http://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html)

I'd like to know if there's any similar combination to copy (selected) text.

Thanks in advance,

Granvic

Comment: [Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: The standard Windows keys are Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V (as well as Ctrl+X for cut); they're used in every single Windows application on the planet that allow cut/copy/paste functionality. Is there a reason you're fighting with the standard to try and use Alt?

Comment: I meant using the alt key or any other sort of combination besides those you refired.

Comment: Scritpts, bots, etc, where I don't need to use those well-known shortcuts.

Comment: The original shortcut keys are [Ctrl]+[Del] and [Shift]+[Insert]. Or [Shift]+[Del] for cut. From the sounds of it, though, you are trying to automate a UI. In that case, faking input is the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ALT+003 to copy selected text for controls that support the ALT+022 combination to paste.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot @TonPlooij

Comment: `Alt+03` should suffice; see [this my answer on `Alt` codes](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602). We could extrapolate (and try it in an open `cmd` window): `Alt+0n` is the same as `Ctrl+X` for all `n`in`1..26` and  `X`in`A..Z` where   `0n to X` relation is as follows: `Alt+01`==`Ctrl+A`, `Alt+02`==`Ctrl+B`, `Alt+03`==`Ctrl+C`, …, `Alt+026`==`Ctrl+Z`